# How to decode a base64 image and getting It's class for my image classification model FastAPI API

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, base64, fastapi

newbie here. I've been working on an image classification model of cats and dogs API.

I have a model, even if it's not that accurate and I get an API from [this tutorial](https://www.machinecurve.com/index.php/2020/03/19/tutorial-how-to-deploy-your-convnet-classifier-with-keras-and-fastapi/) for it, even if it isn't looking fancy, and the code in the end, basically that is my whole API.

It works good if you use a jpg image or other conventional image types when uploaded into "post". But the problem is: my API needs to be able to receive a base64 encoded image and return one of my categories from an array, like:

```
categories = ['dog', 'cat']
```

not a number like the prediction variable API from the tutorial returns.

I found this for the base64 image conversion:

```
 def base64str_to_PILImage(base64str):
  base64_img_bytes = base64.encode("utf-8")
  base64bytes = base64.b64decode(base64_img_bytes)
  bytesObj = io.BytesIO(base64bytes)
  img = Image.open(bytesObj)
  return img
```

But I'm not sure how to integrate this into my API. I've tried to place it onto the "Read image contents" part from the tutorial and I changed the img = Image.open(bytesObj) to:

```
pil_image = Image.open(bytesObj)
return pil_image
```

But FastAPI response body returns me the following internal server error:

```
detail": "encode() missing 1 required positional argument: 'output'
```

I've just got the basics with coding, machine learning stuff with python and APIs . But I'm learning while trying to build this and having some fun with these cute little puppies predictions xD.

Can you guys please help me?

Answer (score 1):

JEZZZ I did it. Okay, I just needed post a question about it and I suddenly found the answer.

To receive an encoded image in base64 and decode it in order to pass it through your model you all  have to do is the following (assuming you have an API similar to mine):

```
[...]
@app.post('/prediction/', response_model=Prediction)
async def prediction_route(file: UploadFile = File(...)):

 try:
   #Read the user posted file
   user_image = await file.read()

   #Decode the received file
   base64bytes = base64.b64decode(user_image)
   bytesObj = io.BytesIO(base64bytes)

   #Open the (now) image file
   pil_image = Image.open(bytesObj)
```

Now you can do whatever the f* you want with the image, by using the "pil_image" variable.

Oh, and in order to get the class from a "categories" array variable all you need is:

```
#Declare it (obviously)
categories = ["dog", "cat"]

#On your base model you have to put a variable from the type of the response you want
#in my case is one of my strings from my categories array
class Prediction(BaseModel):
predicted_class: str
[your other base model stuff]
```

After that:

```
[...]
#use this where you are making your prediction:
[prediction stuff]
predicted_class = categories[np.argmax(prediction)]
```

And finally:

```
#return the predicted class variable with your other responses from the base model
return{
  [your other responses stuff]
  "predicted_class" : predicted_class
```

}

I know it isn't a big deal, but I'm really happy to found this by myself and I hope to help anyone else with this.

Thankss